# How to create Revit add-in and save data in external database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, revit-api, revit

I would like to create a Revit addon that loads some data from Revit model and assosiates them with user entry data. Is there a way to save this associations in the project for future use?Do I have to create a database that keeps these associations, like a local SQLLite or a file localy?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

These are several different questions at once.

How to create a Revit add-in is described in numerous tutorials and other material, much of which is listed by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com) [overview of the Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2).

There are many ways to associate user data with Revit model elements. You can store it in an external database, as you suggest, using either the Revit [element id](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/44f3f7b1-3229-3404-93c9-dc5e70337dd6.htm) or [unique id](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/f9a9cb77-6913-6d41-ecf5-4398a24e8ff8.htm) to maintain an association.

You can also store user data on individual elements within the Revit model by adding it to a shared parameter or using [extensible storage](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#5.23).

I would suggest you work through the getting started material and learn the fundamentals of the Revit API and also the relevant Revit end user workflows for your use case next.

Comment: Thank you so much!I have already created the addon, my main question was regarding saving data in Revit.I was also thinking if there were any hidden parameters that I might use instead.I'm new at this so I will have to search on it!